# how do i group interval by time and do calculation based on ID using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

```
TIME         X             Y       class ID
16:00:06    103.78499   71.45633073 1   A
16:05:06    109.09495   92.82448711 2   A2
16:08:06    105.98095   67.84456255 1   A6
16:11:05    103.461044  71.42452176 3   F4
16:15:05    103.7674    71.47382163 1   C55
16:17:26    107.476204  73.34450468 3   E4
16:18:06    105.27734   87.58118231 2   O8
16:19:21    103.785805  71.44292864 2   H77
16:33:18    103.720085  71.37973541 1   A
17:40:11    107.343185  88.27521372 1   A6
17:43:06    100.84964   67.38097318 2   D
17:45:06    110.1006    66.26799123 2   A
17:50:12    105.854195  87.77078816 2   D4
17:55:09    96.142845   61.99788643 2   F4
18:02:08    103.78293   71.48327491 2   RR3
18:09:33    103.927475  71.49321361 2   U7
18:25:12    104.722595  90.43501546 3   S
18:30:05    109.6942    66.22699393 3   S33
18:33:04    109.71278   97.2428849  3   T17
18:40:44    56.124245   71.13521775 3   G22
18:44:02    93.29675    63.89221211 3   II1
18:50:13    109.70228   71.47756311 1   S9
18:55:11    104.626045  89.71097044 1   B
19:00:06    93.210075   63.85872612 1   A
19:05:04    57.414974   67.63951569 3   D4
19:22:15    103.91814   71.67476075 3   E65
19:24:10    93.26354    67.95513579 3   P9
19:30:16    104.45209   82.10376889 3   Q12
19:40:07    103.7826    71.49702169 2   XX6
19:44:07    103.79914   71.71096234 2   OL4
```

1- Above is a sample of a data frame which has thousands of records.

2- How can group it by the time  (20 min) and class number. Then calculate the Euclidean distance between x, y using :

```
dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
```

3- An iteration of every 20 min for all data, no value duplicates in the single iteration. 
I have tried to implement this sample. but still not working.

[python split a pandas data frame by week or month and group the data based on these sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223360/python-split-a-pandas-data-frame-by-week-or-month-and-group-the-data-based-on-th)

```
The expected results for the 20min in two iteration: 

Iter ID  CLASS  distnace 
1   A,A6    1   4.22695
1   A,C55   1   0.024806
1   A6, C55 1   4.251038
1   A2,O8   2   6.485861
1   A2,H77  2   22.030843
1   O8,H77  2   16.207033
1   F4, E4  3   4.4506
2   A,A6    1   17.279585
```

Comment: Where that has that `Iter` column come from (and how is it A,A6 again with a different distance)?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: the iteration I just add it to explain that the duplicate value( A,A6) can appear in the second 20 min. but cant appear twice in the first 20

Comment: i have tried to implement this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223360/python-split-a-pandas-data-frame-by-week-or-month-and-group-the-data-based-on-th

Comment: Protip: If you're using pandas dataframes, add the pandas tag.